# Why MS Exchange 2013 OWA stuck in "loading", not able to open?

Tags: ssl-certificate, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

I am running MS Exchange 2013. Recently I have been able to open OWA on all browsers until I noticed that I can no longer open OWA in Chrome, Safari, and Opera (**I am seeing a blank page**). I can only open OWA in Internet Explorer and Firefox. I searched on the web and realized that it is related to `Update Issues or SSL Certificates`. First I checked my SSL certificates, they are set to "Microsoft Exchange". According [to this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/dd91598d-3af9-4a98-8493-34726c763c62/owa-failed-to-initialize-after-install-of-rollup-1-for-exchage-sp1) I ran this **UpdateCas.ps1** in PowerShell and it was successful. Now I tried open OWA in Chrome, it showing a blank page **BUT** this time the tab title of the page is showing `Loading` but not opening.

I believe it is *updates related* and running `UpdateCas.ps1` got me one step close to solution.

How do solve this problem? What am I missing? Any links to possible solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues back in the day.

The blank page can occure in one of the following scenarios:

- SSL binding configuration issues
- SSL certificate is missing
- Incorrect time settings in server clock

Most of the times it goes back to SSL issues. Therefore, try to check the currently assigned SSL certificate e.g. `https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/`. Consider to create one with [Letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/)

In IIS go to `Sites` --> `Default Web Site` --> `Bindings` --> `Action` and check the `Site Bindings`. Dont forget to restart IIS afterwards `IISRESET /NOFORCE`

Install the [latest CU](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4037224/cumulative-update-19-for-exchange-server-2013) for exchange 2013. Often reinstalling it solves a lot of configuration issues.